# SQLITE INNER JOIN Wrong results

Tags: python, sqlite

I have the following Sqlite code on python :

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE OB (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , Name TEXT, Item1 TEXT ,item2 TEXT,Item3 TEXT)")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO OB (name,item1,item2,item3) VALUES('Asfoor','a','b','c')")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO OB (name,item1,item2,item3) VALUES('deek','a','x','v')")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO OB (name,item1,item2,item3) VALUES('bata','k','o','p')")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO OB (name,item1,item2,item3) VALUES('wiza','q','w','e')")

con.commit() 
cursor = cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT a.*,b.* from OB a INNER JOIN OB b on a.item1=b.item1  ")
```

It should return only records with item1=item2 so it should return
`'Asfoor','a','b','c'`
`'deek','a','x','v'` 
where item1 in both ='a'
but instead i keep getting them plus getting :
`'bata','k','o','p'`
`'wiza','q','w','e'`
where item1 have different values 
I don't understand why i keep getting those extra wrong results.

It should behave like this but i doesn't
`https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GQmm.png`

Complete output:
    `ID =  1
    NAME =  Asfoor
    Item1 =  a
    Item2 =  b
    Item3 =  c
    ID =  1
    NAME =  Asfoor
    Item1 =  a
    Item2 =  b
    Item3 =  c
    ID =  2
    NAME =  deek
    Item1 =  a
    Item2 =  x
    Item3 =  v
    ID =  2
    NAME =  deek
    Item1 =  a
    Item2 =  x
    Item3 =  v
    ID =  3
    NAME =  bata
    Item1 =  k
    Item2 =  o
    Item3 =  p
    ID =  4
    NAME =  wiza
    Item1 =  q
    Item2 =  w
    Item3 =  e`

Comment: It should behave like https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GQmm.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to replicate your results:

```
import pprint as pp
pp.pprint(cur.execute("""SELECT DISTINCT a.*,b.* 
                           FROM OB a 
                               INNER JOIN OB b 
                               ON a.item1=b.item1;""").fetchall())

[(1, u'Asfoor', u'a', u'b', u'c', 1, u'Asfoor', u'a', u'b', u'c'),
 (1, u'Asfoor', u'a', u'b', u'c', 2, u'deek', u'a', u'x', u'v'),
 (2, u'deek', u'a', u'x', u'v', 1, u'Asfoor', u'a', u'b', u'c'),
 (2, u'deek', u'a', u'x', u'v', 2, u'deek', u'a', u'x', u'v'),
 (3, u'bata', u'k', u'o', u'p', 3, u'bata', u'k', u'o', u'p'),
 (4, u'wiza', u'q', u'w', u'e', 4, u'wiza', u'q', u'w', u'e')]
```

There are matches every time `a.item1 = b.item1`.

Comment: I want it to be done automatically where i don't know the actual value of item1 , i want to get results where item1=item1 only

Comment: I get matches but i keep  getting   'bata','k','o','p' 'wiza','q','w','e' as results as well

Comment: Can you paste your full output into the question?

Comment: Yes ,what do you mean exactly

Comment: Your query seems to return the results I have posted in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

`SELECT DISTINCT a.*,b.* FROM OB AS a INNER JOIN OB AS b ON a.item1=b.item1`

It addresses the alias of tables you tried. You may want to look at a tutorial or documentation about [SQLite aliasing](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_alias_syntax.htm)

Comment: Yes i use aliasing so i can compare rows with item1=item1

Comment: Add the WHERE statement: `WHERE a.item1=b.item2`